# Best performance on x/(y+z) + y/(x+z) + z/(x+y) = N

Tags: math, number-theory, fastest-code, rational-numbers

Consider the equation $$\frac x {y+z} + \frac y {x+z} + \frac z {x+y} = n$$ for positive integers \$x, y, z\$ and \$n \ge 4\$. Your code will receive \$n\$ as an input, and output three integers \$x, y\$ and \$z\$ such that the equation holds. You may assume that a solution always exists.

### Background

This equation is a little bit of a [meme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxqtE.jpg) equation; it's famously difficult to solve, and even the lowest case of \$n = 4\$ took hundreds of years to do so. In [this paper](https://ami.uni-eszterhazy.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_43_from29to41.pdf), the authors present maximum sizes (in digit lengths) for various different \$n\$s, all of which are crazy large. It's pretty clear that a standard brute force approach of iterating through all triples is never going to find the smallest solution for any \$n\$.

However, some pretty clever approaches using [elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) (a curve in the form \$y^2 = x^3 + ax + b\$ for constants \$a, b\$) managed to find a solution for \$n = 4\$:

$$\begin{align*}
x & = 36875131794129999827197811565225474825492979968971970996283137471637224634055579 \\
y & = 154476802108746166441951315019919837485664325669565431700026634898253202035277999 \\
z & = 4373612677928697257861252602371390152816537558161613618621437993378423467772036
\end{align*}$$

Your task is to find these solutions.

### Challenge

Given some positive integer \$n \ge 4\$, you should output three positive integers \$x, y, z\$ such that

$$\frac x {y+z} + \frac y {x+z} + \frac z {x+y} = n$$

You may output any one solution, in any reasonable format and manner, but you must output exactly *one* solution. You may assume that you will only receive inputs where a solution exists.

Additionally, your answer may not fail due to floating point issues.

### Scoring

This is a [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenge, so you should aim for speed over conciseness. I will time each submission on my computer, so:

- You must use a freely available language (that's free as in beer)
- Please provide testing instructions
- If the language is obscure, or requires additional packages/modules, please provide a link to a page where I can download the interpreter

My computer specifications are:
MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). Processor: 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9. Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4. Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB. Retina Display: 16-inch (3072 × 1920). Storage: 208 GB available.

Please test your submission on \$n = 4\$ before submitting, and include a preliminary time (which I will replace with an official score in due time).

#### !! The only valid inputs for \$n ≤ 10\$ are supposedly `4`, `6`, and `10`.

Comment: Is there a name for this equation?

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 0.02s for n=4 on ATO

```
fromellpoint(n, x, y) = [ 8 * (n + 3) - x + y, 8 * (n + 3) - x - y, -8 * (n + 3) - 2 * (n + 2)* x]

{ findellpoint(e, n) =
    my(s, h);
    h = 1;
    until(#s > 0,
        h *= 10;
        s = [ p | p <- ellratpoints(e, h), ellmul(e, p, 6) ]);
    s[1]
}

{ f(n) =
    my(e, x, y, a, b, c);
    e = ellinit([0, 4 * n^2 + 12 * n - 3, 0, 32 * (n + 3), 0]);
    [x, y] = g = findellpoint(e, n);
    while([a, b, c] = fromellpoint(n, x, y);
        a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0,
        [x, y] = elladd(e, g, [x, y]));
    [a, b, c] * denominator([a, b, c])
}

print(f(input))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZJRaoNAEIahj57ih77s2hWMCSWQpBcRW0zUuKDroitNaHqSvqQPpXfqaTqrRlPShYWZn2G-f2b341vHtXzZ6_P5qzWZt_y5W2d1VaZFoSupDFMCB4EjxwYhlnDBFB4w5_BwoOAobkTPit5fNbhkAXdxiBznDZlUyUhJBRQhHNApj6wRyPmqy3ICz_qwVUYW7L7BE3zRKX2BSxX-ahSazqrGie7aAzHq2HSYxnJyLqxWtoXNtMAjRzTAmnAWOe-dO3btJ-2XIBALbAV2Q3lKJGollTQs9AUWNKV6DmjMmR1Y0eBzQV4xD6ZtkHDBhbZpRE32dG_30Re95rJIWTiQbfW_7zPNH2O9gY_TCdsx2nXRtLSRTH3iJLG8vRhUfnE3Il0kqapKqWJT1ZMVblela-siY1Lp1nDef6LhL50_F33wCw)

Not really optimized. PARI/GP has some built-in functions for elliptic curves, so I just use them.

You can download PARI/GP [here](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html).

When you test the code, just save the code into a file, e.g., `a.gp`, and run `echo 4 | gp -fq a.gp` (replace `4` with your input `n`).

Comment: ATO is showing ```overflow in t_INT-->long assignment```  error for n=5,7,8,9

Comment: @Saphereye There is no answer for those input.